# Can somone explain how the traversal for the removal functions in a doubly linked list works?

Tags: java, linux, data-structures, traversal, doubly-linked-list

```
public T removeAt(int index) {
    // Make sure the index provided is valid
    if (index < 0 || index >= size) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    int i;
    Node<T> trav;

    // Search from the front of the list
    if (index < size / 2) {
      for (i = 0, trav = head; i != index; i++) {
        trav = trav.next;
      }
      // Search from the back of the list
    } else
      for (i = size - 1, trav = tail; i != index; i--) {
        trav = trav.prev;
      }

    return remove(trav);
  }
```

Explain how this traversal for the removal of a doubly linked list.
I don't understand the for loop

Answer (score 1):

The only thing this function does is finding the specified element in the list. The actual removal is done by the other method in the last call (`remove(trav)`).

The first `if` just checks whether the specified index exists in the list.

After that, it iterates through the list until it finds the specified element. It uses a temporary Node `trav`. The iteration is simple: get the first object -> get next element if the index is not reached -> get next element etc.

There is a twist though: If the index is in the second half of the list, it iterates backwards from the end of the list. This is a small performance optimisation, since it only has size/2 iterations at max.

Comment: you were faster than me mate. Also, crystal clear answer.

Comment: I just don't understand how the i= 0 correlates with trav = head

Comment: I assume you mean the first expression of the for loop. These are two separate instructions separated by a comma. They both run only once, before the for loop first runs. It is the same as doing i=0; and trav=head; before the loop, but you can't use ; in the for loop because that also separates the conditions and stuff within the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take an example, imagine we had these elements LinkedList:

```
         [1,5,9,11,3] 
indexes-> 0 1 2 3  4
size -> 5
```

Now let's say you want to remove the last element, which has an index of 4, so we call removeAt(4). In order to not traverse all the LinkedList from the start, we instead check if the index is bigger then size/2. 4<2 ? false. Means we start from the tail.
Node trav is basically a pointer to traverse the LinkedList. When you got to that particular index you just call the method remove and pass the current node. remove(trav).